# Pass list of ints from JavaScript to C# -- I get the list, but it is empty; form data isn't structured properly?

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I have my array populated like so:

```
updateLabels: function () {
    var diagrams = _stage.diagramLayer.getChildren();

    var componentIDs = new Array();

    for (var index = 0; index < diagrams.length; index++) {
        componentIDs.push(diagrams[index].componentID);
    }

    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: '../PlanView/UpdateDiagrams',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { ComponentIDs: JSON.stringify(componentIDs), RackInfo: $('#RackInfoSelect').val() },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
    },
```

server side I have this method:

```
[CompressionFilterAttribute]
public JsonResult UpdateDiagrams(List<int> componentIDs, string rackInfo)
{
    List<object> diagramInformation = new List<object>(componentIDs.Count());
}
```

my data as it is being passed across the network:

```
ComponentIDs:[74,445,732,351,348,347,1123,599,600,1053,350,601,602,603,332,99,877,919,349,348,347,347,349,348]
RackInfo:Equipment Weight
```

I successfully get RackInfo, if I change UpdateDiagrams to expect `List<string>` then I get a list with one item in it, the entire ComponentIDs string.

What am I doing incorrectly here?

EDIT: I am working under MVC3. I should be able to leverage some sort of automatic deserialization when passing to my controller, I am just not sure how.

SOLUTION: The solution was to wrap my data object in JSON.stringify, not just componentIDs. Even though I can get the RackInfo variable server-side without converting it to JSON.

Comment: Maybe `componentIDs.push(parseInt(diagrams[index].componentID));`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your posted data to be in JSON format then try something like this. MVC should then be able to deserialise it automatically on the server-side.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../PlanView/UpdateDiagrams',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        componentIDs: componentIDs,
        rackInfo: $('#RackInfoSelect').val()
    }),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

(I'm unable to test it at the moment, but it should hopefully be along the right lines  even if it's not completely bug-free.)

Comment: This worked straight out of the box like a champ. I wonder why I don't always need to call JSON.stringify.

Comment: This code will break when something other than an int gets added into the string by accident. You should sanitize ALL your inputs and parse your values to ints instead of relying on automatic processes that fail when you least expect them to, eventually. And, it makes your app less secure too. All this to avoid one line of code? Code for quality!

Answer (score 2):

You're sending a string that contains a list of strings. When it gets to the server, the string needs to be deserialized.

```
[CompressionFilterAttribute]
public JsonResult UpdateDiagrams(string ListcomponentIDs, string rackInfo)
{
   List<int> componentIDs = (from string s in ListcomponentIDs.Split(',')
                             select Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToList<int>();
}
```

I changed the parameter to a string. When you had it as a list of int, it was an empty list since you were not passing a list of ints.

Also, in the JS, you don't need to serialize the array, just call ToString on it:

```
data: { ComponentIDs: componentIDs.toString() ...
```

So that the data doesn't include the brackets [].

Let me know how this works.

Comment: How can I pass a list of ints which would not need to be /explicitly/ deserialized, then? I know it can be done -- I have seen examples of it being done with more complex objects than ints.

Comment: The whole point of json IS to serialize/deserialize data. See above, I simplified the code a bit.

Comment: And what I am saying is that MVC is supposed to do this for me. See this: http://uliasz.com/2010/07/passing-list-as-parameter-from-ajax-request-to-mvc-controller/

Comment: As much as possible, I stay away from things that do things "automatically". What I'm suggesting works in one line and will be maintainable by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test it with ASP.NET MVC, but if you remove the JSON.stringify everything should work correctly. This is the Form Data without JSON.stringify:

- ComponentIDs[]:10
- ComponentIDs[]:20
- ComponentIDs[]:30
- RackInfo:Equipment Weight

That's the normal way an array is posted to the server.

With JSON.stringify:

- ComponentIDs:[10,20,30]
- RackInfo:Rackinfo

The call to JSON.stringify converts the array to the string "[10, 20, 30]" so you're posting a string to the controller.